# Generate entities with cascade delete

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-tools, hibernate-cascade

I am generating entities for our large database via [JBoss hibernate](http://hibernate.org) [reverse engineering](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html). I was hoping to see cascade annotations in entities, but did not see them on generation.

Is there a way to direct hibernate to consider foreign keys and generate entities with cascade annotations?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it hasn't been documented although this is possible.
It should have been documented at [6.2.4.3. foreign-key](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html#d0e5798).

Look at [hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/master/main/src/java/org/hibernate/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd), there's a **cascade** attribute in elements :

- foreign-key/many-to-one
- foreign-key/one-to-one
- foreign-key/inverse-one-to-one
- foreign-key/set

The **code is the truth** !
Looking at it (hibernate-tools branch 5.2), we can see the possible values of cascade :

For Hibernate in org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.pojo.EntityPOJOClass#**getHibernateCascadeTypeAnnotation** :
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/5.2/src/java/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/pojo/EntityPOJOClass.java#L497
Values are `[ all-delete-orphan, delete-orphan, save-update, replicate, lock, evict ]` (multiple accepted).
The enum type used is *org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType*.

For JPA in org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.pojo.EntityPOJOClass#**getCascadeTypes** :
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/5.2/src/java/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/pojo/EntityPOJOClass.java#L421
Values are `[ persist, merge, delete, refresh, all ]` (multiple accepted).
The enum type used is *javax.persistence.CascadeType*.

Comment: This works really well. e.g.
`<table catalog="db" schema="dbo" name="EntityName" class="EntityName"><foreign-key constraint-name="fk_EntityName_id" ><column-ref local-column="id" foreign-column="foreignId" /><set property="nameOfListProperty" exclude="false" cascade="all"/></foreign-key></table>`